# what difference js file location as hyperlink vs webfolder file

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My jsp is working if 'js' file is included as a hyperlink but not when included as normal js file. what is the issue any suggestion?

**hyperlink** is https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.marquee/1.3.1/jquery.marquee.min.js
Here is the code of the same js file...

```
/**
 * jQuery.marquee - scrolling text like old marquee element
 * @author Aamir Afridi - aamirafridi(at)gmail(dot)com / http://aamirafridi.com/jquery/jquery-marquee-plugin
 */
;(function(d){d.fn.marquee=function(w){return this.each(function(){var a=d.extend({},d.fn.marquee.defaults,w),b=d(this),c,k,p,q,h,l=3,x="animation-play-state",e=!1,B=function(a,b,c){for(var d=["webkit","moz","MS","o",""],e=0;e<d.length;e++)d[e]||(b=b.toLowerCase()),a.addEventListener(d[e]+b,c,!1)},E=function(a){var b=[],c;for(c in a)a.hasOwnProperty(c)&&b.push(c+":"+a[c]);b.push();return"{"+b.join(",")+"}"},g={pause:function(){e&&a.allowCss3Support?c.css(x,"paused"):d.fn.pause&&c.pause();b.data("runningStatus",
"paused");b.trigger("paused")},resume:function(){e&&a.allowCss3Support?c.css(x,"running"):d.fn.resume&&c.resume();b.data("runningStatus","resumed");b.trigger("resumed")},toggle:function(){g["resumed"==b.data("runningStatus")?"pause":"resume"]()},destroy:function(){clearTimeout(b.timer);b.css("visibility","hidden").html(b.find(".js-marquee:first"));setTimeout(function(){b.css("visibility","visible")},0)}};if("string"===typeof w)d.isFunction(g[w])&&(c||(c=b.find(".js-marquee-wrapper")),!0===b.data("css3AnimationIsSupported")&&
(e=!0),g[w]());else{var r;d.each(a,function(c,d){r=b.attr("data-"+c);if("undefined"!==typeof r){switch(r){case "true":r=!0;break;case "false":r=!1}a[c]=r}});a.duration=a.speed||a.duration;q="up"==a.direction||"down"==a.direction;a.gap=a.duplicated?a.gap:0;b.wrapInner('<div class="js-marquee"></div>');var f=b.find(".js-marquee").css({"margin-right":a.gap,"float":"left"});a.duplicated&&f.clone(!0).appendTo(b);b.wrapInner('<div style="width:100000px" class="js-marquee-wrapper"></div>');c=b.find(".js-marquee-wrapper");
if(q){var m=b.height();c.removeAttr("style");b.height(m);b.find(".js-marquee").css({"float":"none","margin-bottom":a.gap,"margin-right":0});a.duplicated&&b.find(".js-marquee:last").css({"margin-bottom":0});var s=b.find(".js-marquee:first").height()+a.gap;a.duration*=(parseInt(s,10)+parseInt(m,10))/parseInt(m,10)}else h=b.find(".js-marquee:first").width()+a.gap,k=b.width(),a.duration*=(parseInt(h,10)+parseInt(k,10))/parseInt(k,10);a.duplicated&&(a.duration/=2);if(a.allowCss3Support){var f=document.body||
document.createElement("div"),n="marqueeAnimation-"+Math.floor(1E7*Math.random()),z=["Webkit","Moz","O","ms","Khtml"],A="animation",t="",u="";f.style.animation&&(u="@keyframes "+n+" ",e=!0);if(!1===e)for(var y=0;y<z.length;y++)if(void 0!==f.style[z[y]+"AnimationName"]){f="-"+z[y].toLowerCase()+"-";A=f+A;x=f+x;u="@"+f+"keyframes "+n+" ";e=!0;break}e&&(t=n+" "+a.duration/1E3+"s "+a.delayBeforeStart/1E3+"s infinite "+a.css3easing,b.data("css3AnimationIsSupported",!0))}var C=function(){c.css("margin-top",
"up"==a.direction?m+"px":"-"+s+"px")},D=function(){c.css("margin-left","left"==a.direction?k+"px":"-"+h+"px")};a.duplicated?(q?c.css("margin-top","up"==a.direction?m:"-"+(2*s-a.gap)+"px"):c.css("margin-left","left"==a.direction?k+"px":"-"+(2*h-a.gap)+"px"),l=1):q?C():D();var v=function(){a.duplicated&&(1===l?(a._originalDuration=a.duration,a.duration=q?"up"==a.direction?a.duration+m/(s/a.duration):2*a.duration:"left"==a.direction?a.duration+k/(h/a.duration):2*a.duration,t&&(t=n+" "+a.duration/1E3+
"s "+a.delayBeforeStart/1E3+"s "+a.css3easing),l++):2===l&&(a.duration=a._originalDuration,t&&(n+="0",u=d.trim(u)+"0 ",t=n+" "+a.duration/1E3+"s 0s infinite "+a.css3easing),l++));q?a.duplicated?(2<l&&c.css("margin-top","up"==a.direction?0:"-"+s+"px"),p={"margin-top":"up"==a.direction?"-"+s+"px":0}):(C(),p={"margin-top":"up"==a.direction?"-"+c.height()+"px":m+"px"}):a.duplicated?(2<l&&c.css("margin-left","left"==a.direction?0:"-"+h+"px"),p={"margin-left":"left"==a.direction?"-"+h+"px":0}):(D(),p={"margin-left":"left"==
a.direction?"-"+h+"px":k+"px"});b.trigger("beforeStarting");if(e){c.css(A,t);var f=u+" { 100%  "+E(p)+"}",g=d("style");0!==g.length?g.filter(":last").append(f):d("head").append("<style>"+f+"</style>");B(c[0],"AnimationIteration",function(){b.trigger("finished")});B(c[0],"AnimationEnd",function(){v();b.trigger("finished")})}else c.animate(p,a.duration,a.easing,function(){b.trigger("finished");a.pauseOnCycle?b.timer=setTimeout(v,a.delayBeforeStart):v()});b.data("runningStatus","resumed")};b.bind("pause",
g.pause);b.bind("resume",g.resume);a.pauseOnHover&&b.bind("mouseenter mouseleave",g.toggle);e&&a.allowCss3Support?v():b.timer=setTimeout(v,a.delayBeforeStart)}})};d.fn.marquee.defaults={allowCss3Support:!0,css3easing:"linear",easing:"linear",delayBeforeStart:1E3,direction:"left",duplicated:!1,duration:5E3,gap:20,pauseOnCycle:!1,pauseOnHover:!1}})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Are you appending `<script>` before and after the code ?

Comment: No script was appended.  i need jquery marquee plugin that supports in all ie versions

Answer (score 0):

make sure that your file location is correct (check it via View Page Source or inspect element) and set your permission file into 777.

Comment: **Error is Object doesn't support property or method 'marquee'** in function ------ jQuery('.marquee1').marquee({
   allowCss3Support: true,
   css3easing: 'linear',
   easing: 'linear',
   delayBeforeStart: 0,
   direction: 'up',
   duplicated: true,
   duration: 10000,
   gap: 10,
   pauseOnCycle: false,
   pauseOnHover: false,
   startVisible: false
});